# shift-insert ctrl-insert in windows shell console

Tags: windows, shell, copy-paste

I'd like to use a keystroke to copy and paste between a shell window and an editor in Windows 7 (e.g. between a cygwin shell running irb and emacs). `Ctrl-insert` and `Shift-insert` would work nicely, but when I use those in my shell, they simply print out `;5~` and `;2~` instead of actually copying and pasting. Is there a way to get them to actually copy and paste in the shell?

Comment: Alt-Space, E, K, mark your region, Enter to copy. Alt-Space, E, P to paste.

Comment: Well, yes, I know about that. I was hoping to get a simple keystroke working instead of going through the menus using a series of keystrokes. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually decided to go with [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), a shell alternative. It allows me to assign whatever key-strokes I want to copy/paste. I wish I'd known about it a long time ago. Works great so far.